# Quarkus and Redis

Tags: java, caching, redis, quarkus

Im using REDIS to cache in Quarkus Application but sometimes I got an error saying that "Client is closed" when I try to access key/values from it.

```
WARN  [io.net.uti.con.AbstractEventExecutor] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-2) A task raised an exception. Task: io.vertx.core.http.impl.pool.Pool$$Lambda$1087/0x0000000801418c40@b245c25: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client is closed
```

I have **Injected redisClient** in a singleton class and use it to get/create/delete cache.

My Redis class:

```
@Singleton
public class Redis{

        @Inject
        RedisClient redisClient;

    public String add(final String key, final String value) {
        return redisClient.set(Arrays.asList(key, value)).toString();
    }

    public String get(final String key) {
        return redisClient.get(key).toString();
    }
}
```

To access those methods I have Injected this class:

```
class XPTO {
  ...
  @Inject
  Redis redis;
  ...

  public test() {

    String cache = redis.add("allRegisters2", "abc");
  }
```

**Note:**

- My Redis is running in docker all the time and I can access it via Redis explorer from Intellij.
- Sometimes I can access but on the second attempt the client connection is shutdown.

**Any idea what is happening or a clue of what is causing the problem?**

Comment: I got the same problem. It always happens after a hot-reload when using quarkusDev. I just submitted a PR that should fix the issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/13122